# UITextField doesn't scroll to the end after implementing textRectForBounds and editingRectForBounds in a subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField subclass where I am implementing the methods below:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

  return CGRectInset(bounds , 30, 7);
}

-(CGRect) editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
  return CGRectInset(bounds , 30, 7);
}
```

Because of these two methods, the `UITextField` doesn't scroll to the end when the text entered gets bigger than the width of `UITextField`. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Are you implementing these to create an inset around the text? There are other ways to achieve that, perhaps less buggy.

Comment: Are you sure you are not overriding something else? Because I made a simple test project with a custom text fiel, just overriding with the 2 methods above and the text scrolls horizontally to the end.

Comment: Its working proper if you put your textfield direct in xib, because adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth option is already set "YES". but if you do dynamic allocation of textfield class, you should have to set textFieldObject.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

Answer (score 12):

Its not working just because of the font size of the text you have declared in `UITextField` and the `CGRectInset` you are applying. Actually it should be as per the font size you are setting. For example, for font size of 14.0, just change your method as below:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds , 30, 6);
}
-(CGRect) editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds , 30, 6);
}
```

The reason is that the drawing rectangle of the text. For example, when we set font size of `UITextField` as 14.0 then it requires at least a height of 18.0 to adjust the text in the frame. So it needs 4 pixel extra around the text, you can say it overlay frame. Due to which, in your case, this condition is not satisfying because as far as I guess you have adjusted the font size to 14.0 and as by default frame height of `UITextField` is 30.0 and your edge masking is of 7.0 each side that means total 14.0. So your rect for text returns 16.0 which in turn blocks the OS from updating the text frame because it is outside of the graphics context. I hope you are clear.

More good answer will be as follows:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
return CGRectInset(bounds , 30, (30 - self.font.pointSize - 4)/2);
}

-(CGRect) editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds , 30, (30 - self.font.pointSize - 4)/2);
}
```

Comment: One problem I see here is that this answer considers `-[UIFont pointSize]` interchangeable with pixel distances.

Comment: Thats not a reason for your down vote. Check the answer then do down vote. The font size is considered to calculate the maximum edge mask for the UITextField for a particular font size. And as far as i know the font size to pixel conversion is totally dependent on iOS whether it is retina/plain.

Comment: Please don't edit my answer to make it meaningless.. The figures are exact what i have written.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a conflict between your custom `UITextField` `CALayer` height with insets and it's font size.

You may try one of these adjusts:

- Decrease font size;
- Increase the `UITextField` height on `Storyboard` or programmatically in your subclass like:

  ```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
      CGRect frameRect = self.frame;
      frameRect.size.height = 35 //specify the height you want;
      self.frame = frameRect;
   }
  ```
- Decrease the y-coordinate value on `CGRectInset`;
- Or use `UIEdgeInsets` to have more control in setting values ​​of each position. Something like:

  ```
  - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
      UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 30, 5, 30);
      return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, contentInsets);
  }

  - (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{
      UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 30, 5, 30);
      return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, contentInsets);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Reason - You are using fixed font size for textfield text.
Use this

```
 textFieldObject.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Short and simple. If you want to set your minimum font size you can use this

```
 textFieldObject.minimumFontSize
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but modifying `editingRectForBounds` the following way, will make the inset dynamic so once the textbox get's "full", it will lessen the inset so the text will fill the whole textbox.

assuming `textInset_` is the wanted inset:

```
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGFloat compensate = .0f;
    CGSize size = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font];
    CGFloat textboxWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.width);

    // If size of text plus inset (right side) is bigger
    // than textbox's width, don't set an inset
    if (size.width+textInset_ >= textboxWidth) {
        compensate = 0;
    }

    // If text area (textbox width minus two insets) is less than
    // text size, lessen the inset so the text fits in 
    else if (textboxWidth - textInset_*2 < size.width) {
        compensate = fabs(size.width - (textboxWidth - textInset_));
    }

    // Text fits in textbox WITH insets
    else {
        compensate = textInset_;
    }
    return CGRectInset(bounds, compensate, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
step 1 - make a custom text field MyTextField first

@interface MyTextField : UITextField
step 2 - override MyTextField methods as per your requirement

///place holder position

- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
 {
   return CGRectInset(bounds, 8, 8);
 }
 // text position
 - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

  return CGRectInset(bounds, 8,4);
 }

 // text position while editing
 - (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

     return CGRectInset(bounds, 8, 4);
 }
step 3- import MyTextField in your controller class & make object of MyTextField

#import "MyTextField.h"

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    MyTextField* textfield1 = [[MyTextField alloc] init];
    // and so on

}
```

With Reference to this link :

[- (CGRect) textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272800/cgrect-textrectforboundscgrectbounds-not-being-called)